# Create spring:beans root in lxml

Tags: python, spring, spring-mvc, lxml

I'm trying to create xml with lxml.etree module for python2. It would be an easy task if not requirement that output should looks like:

```
<spring:beans xmlns="http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
```

http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/ http://membrane-soa.org/schemas/proxies-1.xsd">

any suggestion how can I do that? All I was able to achieve at this moment is:

```
<ns0:beans xmlns:ns0="http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/"/>
```

so how to have "spring" instead of "ns0"

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lxml tag name with a ":"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432912/lxml-tag-name-with-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map to declare the namespaces and use `None` as the key specifically for default namespace :

```
from lxml import etree as ET

nsmap = { None: "http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/", 
          "spring": "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans",
          "xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" }
root = ET.Element("{%s}beans" % nsmap["spring"], nsmap=nsmap)
root.set("{%s}schemaLocation" % nsmap["xsi"], 
         "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd")
```

**result :** (after formatting)

```
<spring:beans 
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://membrane-soa.org/proxies/1/" 
    spring:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd"
/>
```