# python lxml add item name with ilegal caractes

Tags: python, lxml

i want to build xml for wordpress using python,

this is my current code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lxml.etree
import lxml.builder 
from lxml import etree   

E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
RSS = E.rss
channel = E.channel
ITEM = E.item
FIELD1 = E.field1
FIELD2 = E.field2
title = E.title
link = E.link
description = E.description
pubDate = E.pubDate
language = E.language

the_doc = RSS(
    channel(
        title("feed rss test by python"),
        link("https://localhost/"),
        description("description site"),
        pubDate("Mon, 23 Sep 2019 10:25:12 +0000"),
        language("en-US"),
    )
)

tmp = ITEM(
        title("title"),
        link("link"),
        pubDate("Mon, 23 Sep 2019 10:25:12 +0000"),
        description("test description"),
    )  

the_doc.append(RSS(channel(tmp)))

test = lxml.etree.tostring(the_doc, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-16')

with open("data.xml", 'wb') as output:
    output.write(test)
```

the code is working, my problem is i want to add new item `wp:status` in table ITEM and python not allow to declare variables with : ... how i can declare xml item with name `wp:status` ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432912/lxml-tag-name-with-a. The `:` is used to build namespaces, so you cannot add like that. You need to use the syntax for namespaces.

Comment: I think this was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58137296/407651

Answer (score 0):

If i got your quesiton correctly you need to make a tag named "wp:status" through the xml.builder.ElementMaker factory.

According tho [the docs](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.builder.ElementMaker-class.html) this can be done with the other api `E` exposes:

```
E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker()
wp_status = E("wp:status")

tmp = ITEM(
    wp_status("cool status"),
     ...
)
```

Comment: ValueError: Invalid tag name 'wp:status' not working in this way :(